# Displaying objects depending on List size

Tags: c#, wpf

Im writing a Tetris remake, and I have a little problem with displaying my blocks. 
So basically I store all my squares(rectangles) in 2-dimensional array(for example [0,0] is rectangle in col=0, row=0) and I'm changing their visibility property to show/hide them. I store the blocks to be displayed in a List. Here's my method which suppose to display the rectangles which are not moving at the moment (hardcoded for 4 rectangles just to show how it works):

```
        public void DisplayStationary(List<int> stationaryBlocks)
    {
        rectangles[stationaryBlocks[0], stationaryBlocks[1]].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        rectangles[stationaryBlocks[2], stationaryBlocks[3]].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        rectangles[stationaryBlocks[4], stationaryBlocks[5]].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        rectangles[stationaryBlocks[6], stationaryBlocks[7]].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
  }
```

This is how it looks when I only display 4 rectangles(8 items in list), but I want it to change dynamically, as the list of blocks grows. For example for 8 rectangles to display it would be 16 items on the list and so on.

Any hints on how should I change my method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this for the interior of your `Display(List<int> blocks)` method

```
for(var i = 0; i < stationaryBlocks.Count(); i=i+2;) {
    // don't use i++ for "second" block as that is assignment and will mess up the loop
    rectangles[blocks[i], blocks[i+1]].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! Well it was pretty obvious solution, Im just completly new to Lists